# What are common exceptions that need to be handled while creating laravel api?

Tags: laravel, exception

I am currently new to exceptions handling. What are the exceptions that need to be handled??

I have found only these exceptions:
`NotFoundHttpException`,
`ModelNotFoundException`

Are there any other common exceptions that needs to be handled?? And when the exception will be encountered?

Comment: What are you going to do with them when you're handling them?

Comment: @apokryfos I just want to know about the available exceptions and when it will take place..

Comment: There's a lot of them. However you don't actually need to handle any of them unless you know exactly what you're going to do with it. The [boilerplate exception handler](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Exceptions/Handler.php) deals with most use cases and you can add more as you encounter them

Comment: @apokryfos i have only encountered above exceptions. And i want to know that are there any others exceptions that user may commonly get while using application?

Answer (score 0):

`MethodNotAllowedException`
`TokenMismatchException`,
`NotFoundHttpException` and `ModelNotFoundException`